# PUT request with without every field from the DTO model

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core

I want to make PUT request in ASP .NET CORE that user can make to update his note.
It's my UpdateNoteDTO:

```
    public class UpdateNoteDto
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string NoteBody { get; set; }
        public int Color { get; set; }
    }
```

and it's my Update method:

```
        public void Update(UpdateNoteDto dto, int noteID)
        {
            var note = _dbContext
                       .Notes
                       .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == noteID);
            
            if (note is null)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException("Note not found");
            }

            note.NoteTitle = dto.NoteTitle == string.Empty
                             || dto.NoteTitle is null 
                             ? note.NoteTitle : dto.NoteTitle;

            note.NoteBody = dto.NoteBody == string.Empty 
                            || dto.NoteBody is null 
                            ? note.NoteBody : dto.NoteBody;

            note.Color = dto.Color == 1 ? note.Color : dto.Color;

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I want to make request that user can make to change single field without need for declare all of them. This code what i wrote is working but i bet there is better solution for this :D

Comment: PATCH is a better method than PUT for partial updates.

Comment: That looks like a standard way to do such things

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it looks fine but I would suggest two changes,

1. If you plan to use the endpoint for updating one or some values it's better to change request type to PATCH, the HTTP PATCH request method applies partial modifications to a resource whereas HTTP PUT changes whole resource.
2. To easily add conditions for mapping DTOs to entity models I would rather use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper) which allows user to declare mapping conditions in a single spot and use IMapper interface to map the models.
   For example if you have two classes:

```
public class UpdateNoteDto
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string NoteBody { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
}


public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NoteTitle { get; set; }
    public string NoteBody { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
}
```

you can map them by creating a mapping profile with conditions instead of using if, switch or any other way of comparing whether to map or not

mapping Profile could look like this:

```
public class NoteProfile: Profile
{
    public NoteProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UpdateNoteDto, Note>()  
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NoteTitle, opt => opt.Condition(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.NoteTitle)))  
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NoteBody, opt => opt.Condition(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.NoteBody)))  
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Color, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Color != default))  
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());  
    }
}
```

and update the `Update(UpdateNoteDto dto, int noteID)` function correspondingly:

```
public void Update(UpdateNoteDto dto, int noteID)
{
    var noteToUpdate = _dbContext
               .Notes
               .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == noteID);

    if (note is null)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException("Note not found");
    }

    var note = _mapper.Map(dto, note);

    _dbContext.Update(note);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like that, thank you ! :D

Comment: Gad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

**client** should handled  this issue

Or

if you want update an entity, it is better to use **PATCH**

If the client wants the previous data ***not to be edited***
It should **send** you the **previous data**

Maybe, for example, the user wants to field the "NoteBody" value as empty In which case it cannot do this